# SSRS Reportviewer Cannot add duplicate collection entry of type 'add' with unique key attribute 'name' set to 'ReportViewerWebControlHandler'

Tags: c#, reporting-services, reportviewer, handlers, ssrs-2016

Hey all I am pulling out my hair trying to figure out why this is telling me that there are duplicates of the key for **ReportViewerWebControlHandler**.

[image]

This is what my **web.config** file looks like (omitting things that do not apply here)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false" />
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false" />
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false" />
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="30" />
    <machineKey validationKey="****" decryptionKey="****" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" />
    <compilation defaultLanguage="c#" targetFramework="4.5.1" debug="true">
      <buildProviders>
        <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      </buildProviders>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
        <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" maxRequestLength="6000" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <!--<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Account/error?type=000">
      <error statusCode="401" redirect="~/Account/error?type=401" />
      <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/Account/error?type=403" />
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Account/error?type=404" />
      <error statusCode="405" redirect="~/Account/error?type=405" />
      <error statusCode="408" redirect="~/Account/error?type=408" />
      <error statusCode="409" redirect="~/Account/error?type=409" />
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/Account/error?type=500" />
    </customErrors>-->
    <httpCookies httpOnlyCookies="true" requireSSL="false" />
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler,   Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0,   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" validate="false"  />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

If I do go ahead and take out **< add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler...** the page loads up and once I click on my report to display it I get the error of:

Report Viewer Configuration Error

> The Report Viewer Web Control HTTP Handler has not been registered in
>   the application's web.config file. Add  to the system.web/httpHandlers
>   section of the web.config file, or add  to the system.webServer/handlers
>   section for Internet Information Services 7 or later.

[image]

So now it seems to want the **< add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler...** placed back into the web.config file???

Just for kicks I added the **< add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler...** back in but took out the **< add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"...** and got the same error (500.19) error....

And if I go ahead and take out BOTH then the page loads up and once I click on my report to display it I get the error **Report Viewer Configuration Error** again...

I'm not seeing anything that looks like a duplicate in this???? Can anyone point me to what is wrong with my web.config file???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same problem. I added `remove` section under the handlers section and it solved my problem

```
<handlers>
<remove name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" />
<add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
</handlers>
```

Answer (score 0):

to the system.web/httpHandlers section of the web.config file, or add  to the system.webServer/handlers

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).