# IsPostBack is not set when pool in Integrated mode

Tags: asp.net, web-config, reportviewer, httphandler, application-pool

I have a page with a single `ReportViewer` (v.15) that shows a report, the loading routine resides in `Page_Load` inside an `if (!IsPostBack)` block, and like always in debug everything works just fine. But when I publish it onto a remote server running `IIS 10` I'm getting a constantly loading report, with a single exception in console as follows:
[image: Exception]
I've found that for some reason when report loads and posts back to get the data the `IsPostBack` stays `false` effectively reloading the report. After digging it for two days I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20524366/1707245), then seen [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55257878) and tried to switch the `Application Pool Mode` to classic, and everything started to work as expected. I believe it's some kind of misconfiguration, but I can't find what and where.
Bellow is relevant parts of code and configuration:

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Title="Test Report" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Reporting._Default" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" runat="server" EnableTelemetry="false" height="980" width="800" ShowExportControls="true" ShowPrintButton="true" AsyncRendering="true" SizeToReportContent="true">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</asp:Content>
```

Site.Master

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Reporting.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%: Page.Title %> :: SSRS</title>

    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <%: Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr") %>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>

    <webopt:bundlereference runat="server" path="~/Content/css" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManagerMaster" runat="server">
            <Scripts>
                <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
                <%--Framework Scripts--%>
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="respond" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
                <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
                <%--Site Scripts--%>
            </Scripts>
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <div class="container body-content">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <hr />
            <footer>
                <p>SSRS</p>
            </footer>
        </div>

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Web.config:

```
<system.web>
  <compilation targetFramework="4.8">
    <buildProviders>
      <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    </buildProviders>
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebDesign, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.DataVisualization, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Design, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
      <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    </assemblies>
  </compilation>
  <httpHandlers>
    <add path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" verb="*"
         type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" validate="false" />
  </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
  <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <remove name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" />
    <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    <remove name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" />
    <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" preCondition="integratedMode"
         type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

I tried to remove parts of `Web.config` that belong to `Classic Mode` (the `httpHandlers`, `validateIntegratedModeConfiguration` and `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`) but it didn't help...

Comment: The [httpHandlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/bya7fh0a(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#elementInformationToggle) element is used on sites running on IIS 5 – 6, or IIS 7.x in Classic mode (IIS 6 compatibility mode).  The [handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/settings-schema/ms689475(v=vs.90)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#elementInformationToggle) element is used on sites running on IIS 7.x (Integrated mode).

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Yeah, I know that, that's why I tried to remove it along with `validateIntegratedModeConfiguration ` attribute that prevents migration error message. Can you think of a reason why in this case `IsPostBack` works well in `Classic mode`, but stops in `Integrated mode`?

Comment: Could you share which iis feature you enabled?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal do you need the list of all modules? like `IsapiModule`, `RewriteModule` etc.?

Comment: did you enable asp.net feature?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Definitely